# How to detect broken/recovered JMS connection in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

We are building an integration project using Apache Camel (Camel 2.10.3, Java DSL based).

We have a route that extracts data from a database (lets call it IN_DB), does some logic and inserts into another database (OUT_DB) once a day, and another route that subscribes to a JMS topic for XML data, does some logic and inserts it into the same database (OUT_DB) throughout the day.

The requirement is that when the JMS topic connection goes down for whatever reason, we keep trying to reconnect indefinitely, and once reconnection is successful we need to go back to the database (IN_DB) and do another load to fill in the gap where the topic was down.

My question is how can we do this logic ('I was connected then I got disconnected and now I am connected again') in Camel? What happens to the route that starts with a topic consumer when the topic goes down, will the route just stop? Or will it issue an error message to some error queue? Do I have to write my own handler to monitor the topic connection, or will Camel automatically reconnect when the topic comes back up and set some message header, or set some context variable to indicate that the 'I was connected then I got disconnected and now I am connected again' scenario has happened? I am happy building the route logic around calling the database load I just can't figure out the best way to 'detect' in Camel that this scenario has happened.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of the reconnecting to your queue, it depends on what JMS broker you are using. If you are using ActiveMQ then you can configure how it reconnects through the URI so it can try and reconnect to another broker, reconnect to the same broker after a timeout etc. The docs for it are [here](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html).

To detect when the connection has failed, the easiest from the point of the view of the program is to just use persistent queues instead of topics. However, assuming that isn't feasible then I think you've got two options.

1. Define a [JMS exception listener](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html). This should let you know when the underlying connection has disappeared.

To detect when its back up again I think you're stuck with posting a message to a particular topic and watching for messages from this topic in another route. When you read a message on this topic, you know the broker has come back up so you can reload your data from the DB.

or 2. You could post regular hearbeat messages onto your JMS topic. If you stop receiving them you know the broker has gone down. Once you start to get them again, you know it is back up and you need to reload data from the DB.

Comment: Thanks Matt, some excellent suggestions here. Unfortunately, we do not own the topics we are subscribing to (Tibco EMS broker), and are connecting with read-only accounts which makes the heartbeat approach a bit tricky. Where would the JMS exception be thrown from? The JMSComponent itself, or the route consuming from it?

Comment: You do seem to be a bit stuck for options! I haven't got an example to hand but the exception listener is registered on the connection so the exception should be thrown by the connection rather than from somewhere in the route. Your only other option is to query IN_DB regularly to see if it has any messages that you don't know about but I suspect that isn't practical either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer some years later ! I was looking for a solution for this problem since a few days, in order to supervising an AMQP connection in an Apache Camel application.

I finally find a way, I do not know if in the last Camel versions (i am using 2.25.4), it is possible do listen more "natively" the JMS connection changes :

- The JMS consumer route must use the option "messageListenerContainerFactory" in the URL : `"messageListenerContainerFactory=#customJmsListernerContainerFactory"`

The factory would be instancied before of course and added to a registry associated to the camel context :

```
MessageListenerContainerFactory customJmsListenerContainerFactory = new CustomJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        this.registry.put("customJmsListernerContainerFactory", customJmsListenerContainerFactory);
```

- not working on producer, for this kind, you must add an exception clause :
  onException(javax.jms.JMSException.class)...
- create the class CustomJmsListenerContainerFactory used above, implementing MessageListenerContainerFactory :

  ```
    public class CustomJmsListenerContainerFactory implements MessageListenerContainerFactory {


    @Override
    public AbstractMessageListenerContainer createMessageListenerContainer(JmsEndpoint endpoint) {

        CustomJmsListenerContainer customJmsListener = new CustomJmsListenerContainer();

        return customJmsListener;
    }
  ```
- create a class CustomJmsListenerContainer extending DefaultMessageListenerContainer AND implementing JmsConnectionListener. The trick is to ovveride createConnection, in order to temporary get the created connection in order to manually add a listener (the container itself):

  ```
    public class CustomJmsListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer implements JmsConnectionListener {

    protected Connection createConnection() throws JMSException {
        JmsConnection myConnection = (JmsConnection)super.createConnection();
        this.myConnection.addConnectionListener(this);
        return myConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionEstablished(URI remoteURI) {
        LOGGER.info("JMS connection detected");


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailure(Throwable error) {
        LOGGER.info("JMS connection failure");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionInterrupted(URI remoteURI) {
        LOGGER.info("JMS connection interrupted");

    @Override
    public void onConnectionRestored(URI remoteURI) {
        LOGGER.info("JMS connection restored");

    @Override
    public void onInboundMessage(JmsInboundMessageDispatch envelope) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionClosed(Session session, Throwable cause) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConsumerClosed(MessageConsumer consumer, Throwable cause) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProducerClosed(MessageProducer producer, Throwable cause) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  ```

  }