Apache Camel sending message to jms component
I'm currently sending messages to an activemq. So until the connection is established to this queue the messages gets delivered. If there is a connection lost to the active mq the messages that are supposed to be sent are lost in this phase.
My solution to overcome this . Save all the messages to be sent in a DB, create a timer route and pick the message in a lot and then send to the active mq. Please note that the order of the messages needs to be in place. This implementation is coming at a cost as I will have to think about not picking the same messages again. If i think of maintaining the order what if a message picked up by the timer route is again undelivered as the connection was still down .
Please help me figure out is there a better solution which is provided by apache camel itself to streamline this functionality ? a configuration/setting such that during the disconnection with the activemq , all the messages are piled up in a cache and when connection is back , first the cache messages are sent and then the normal flow will continue.

Why connection is lost ? In fact if activemq connection is lost why DB connection is not lost ?

to check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633917/how-to-detect-broken-recovered-jms-connection-in-apache-camel

DB is related to my service . activemq is hosted in some other server. I'm looking for a solution such that i don't loose any message in this transition

You can manage timeout to wait that connection come back, message will wait in memory.

yes exactly I want to know more about this memory where and how it can be saved ? Can you Please elaborate

The thread will wait with all its variables. If there is a timeout exception you need to catch and to put message in FIFO stack for exemple.
